# iOS - CGImageRef Potential Leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cgimageref

I have this code:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *outputimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                                           scale:image.scale
                                     orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

and I get the warning:

> Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'imageRef' is not
>   referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

But I am using ARC and cannot use `release` or `autoRelease`. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this code

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

From `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` document,

> The resulting image retains a reference to the original image, which means you may release the original image after calling this function.

So,what you need to do is just call `CGImageRelease` to make it retain count -1